# Position of HTML attributes breaks embedding images

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, editor, images

I want to embed an image of this beautiful unicorn.

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHnAW.png"/>
```

[image]

Perfect! Now, it's a little too … majestic, so I'd like to make it smaller. Markdown doesn't support it, but we can use HTML, right?

```
<img width="100" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHnAW.png"/>
```

… but where's the image? It's just not displayed! Check the source code of this question to see it. So, let's shuffle those attributes around:

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHnAW.png" width="100"/>
```

[image]

**Now it works!** Obviously, the attribute position matters, and the image is just not displayed. As we all know, the position of attributes shouldn't matter, therefore, please make it possible to specify `width` (and other allowed attributes) anywhere inside the tag.

Comment: I like green unicorns.

Comment: I'm inexplicably compelled to upvote your comment @AndrewBarber.

Comment: Does this work only with PNG but not JPEG images?

Comment: @BasilBourque Image format shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 5):

I'm quite sure this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). Quoting from [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites):

> You must enter the tags exactly as shown. Any deviation from this list (adding extra spaces, using single quote or no quotes, etc) means the tag will be stripped.

From the list,

```
src=""
width="" (up to 999)
height="" (up to 999)
alt=""
title=""
```

`src` must come before `width` and `height`.

Comment: Yep. It's pretty strict, but it makes the sanitizer implementation very straightforward.

Comment: Well, it still manifests like a bug though – and there's a difference between "straightforward" and inflexible :) The question you linked to does not explicitly state that the ordering of attributes *needs* to be like this.

Comment: @slhck Uh, yes it does. Okay, maybe Jeff might have confused terms "tags" and "attribute", but I'm quite sure he meant the attributes must be entered in that order.

Comment: Concerning attributes, it only mentions *The following attributes are allowed* – nothing about their order. Again, it does not *explicitly* say anything. Not that it matters, but it's not that obvious from the description and apparently a very unusual form of sanitizing.

Comment: @slhck I think he's referring to "*You must enter the tags exactly as shown.*".  I think "changing the order of the attributes" should probably be added to the parenthetical list of examples to clarify.

Comment: I agree with keeping the sanitizer simple.  But perhaps the user should be at least be notified about *why* their tag was stripped?