# Match IMG max-width in bios to the width of the bio pane

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, design

After banging my head against the wall trying to manually resize an image in my bio because the sanitizer was [hyper-sensitive to the position of attributes in an HTML element](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121395/position-of-html-attributes-breaks-embedding-images), I was curious why it didn't clamp the width anyways like in posts.

There seems to be CSS that clamps IMG elements in posts (`post-text`) to a `max-width: 640px`, could there be a similar rule for the "About Me" section?